# Landed on a hot and cold planet, short life spans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story or novella where the people hide in caves during the really hot days and cold nights. They have highly accelerated life spans. The protagonist tries to journey to a metal spaceship. I think food and life outside the cave appear rapidly at morning twilight and burn to a crisp by mid-morning.

Comment: Is there anything else you can remember? Why don't you look at [this page](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if any other details come to your mind.

Comment: Note that duplicate target is already the target of two other closed duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across [Frost and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29)  by [Ray Bradbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Bradbury),

> Placed there by a past rocket ship that crashed, the people of the storied land are within sight of another rocket ship on a distant mountain plateau. The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation to live only eight days.

Accelerated lifespan

> The people of this planet are also gifted with racial memory (they remember their ancestors' memories). However, they do not attempt to reach the sole remaining rocket ship due to the futility of attempting to reach it in one hour, which is the longest length of time between day and night (both deadly).

Day and night can kill them

> Sim is then moved by the memory of his ancestors to find and meet with scientists who make halting progress towards the goal of lengthening the world's decreased life span. Sim, motivated by his dwindling days, makes it his goal to extend his life and reach the distant rocket, despite the protests of his sister and other cave-dwellers.

The protagonist has to reach the ship they crash landed in

Comment: This story [has come up before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstory-identification%5d%20is%3aanswer%20bradbury%20frost). You can read it at the Internet Archive, under the alternative title ["The Creatures that Time Forgot"](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v03n04_1946-Fall#page/n95/mode/2up).

Comment: I'm sure that's it, thanks much. Can't wait to read it again, been haunting me.